# How to lowercase Azure DevOps pipeline variables names

Tags: azure, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

May you please suggest how to lowercase the environment name in Azure DevOps pipelines.

[image]

When environment name is "Test" I want account name to be `myprefixtest`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is an option to do to lower when you use the task (like in your Azure CLI task), but you can add a small PowerShell script that does it before the Azure CLI task:

```
$envName = "$(Release.EnvironmentName)"
$lower = $envName.ToLower()
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Release.EnvironmentName;]$lower"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [lower](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)? This might help with what you are trying to do.